# R Highcharter custom barchart function error

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I want to create a custom function with the `highcharter` package, since I have to plot many barcharts where just the tooltip changes.

This works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)


highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(zoomType = "x") %>%
    hc_add_series(data = mtcars, type = "bar", hcaes(y = mpg))
```

This does not:

```
barchartfunction1 <- function(df, yvar) {

    highchart() %>%
        hc_chart(zoomType = "x") %>%
        hc_add_series(data = df, type = "bar", hcaes(y = yvar))
}

barchartfunction1(mtcars, yvar = mpg)

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: yvar.
Called from: mutate_impl(.data, dots)
```

I was pretty sure this is due to non-standard-evaluation in Highcharter, so I tried this:

```
barchartfunction2 <- function(df, yvar) {

    yvar <- enquo(yvar)

    highchart() %>%
        hc_chart(zoomType = "x") %>%
        hc_add_series(data = df, type = "bar", hcaes(y = !!yvar))
}

  Column `y` is of unsupported type quoted call
Called from: mutate_impl(.data, dots)
```

Ok, Highcharter does not like the quoted call... Is this the wrong way? No NSE here? Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: In `barchartfunction2`, replace `enquo` with either `substitute` or `rlang::enexpr` Ref: Hadley Wickham's Advanced R, *19.3.1 Capturing expressions* (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html).

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. This topic is still quite confusion to me, even with some experience.